# Unknown Source in Stacktrace with JBoss and Proxying

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception, jboss

I've got the following stacktrace that apparently produces NullPointerException at runtime:

```
2023-04-10 13:54:50,790 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default-threads - 44) [ ] [null ] [ ] [ ] [ ] JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component VotingResultsHelper for method public void com.example.voting.impl.helpers.VotingResultsHelper.calculateNewProtocol(com.example.voting.api.dto.request.OnlineVotingProtocolMakeRequest,com.example.voting.impl.persistence.model.VotingVersion):

.... 

    at com.example.voting.impl.helpers.VotingResultsHelper$$$view1332.calculateNewProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4488.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at com.example.voting.impl.helpers.VotingResultsHelper$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.calculateNewProtocol(VotingResultsHelper$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at com.example.voting.impl.VotingMessageServiceImpl.makeOnlineVotingProtocol(VotingMessageServiceImpl.java:661)

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Presumably, the exception occured in the `calculateNewProtocol()` method of the `com.example.voting.impl.helpers.VotingResultsHelper` class.

I need to know just a few things:

1. Is there a way to find out where exactly the exception occurred in the proxied version of the `com.example.voting.impl.helpers.VotingResultsHelper` class? Do I need to build/deploy the app in a different way to accomplish this? Why does it give the unknown for `calculateNewProtocol()` but not for `makeOnlineVotingProtocol()`?
2. The `calculateNewProtocol()` method calls other private methods. Is there a guarantee that the exception occurred in this method and not in the private methods? There are no other methods in the stacktrace.

Comment: Anything calling a private method must be called in code inside that private methods class, and for package private, the calling method must be inside at least the code of an extended class! If you change the method to protected along with any globals that may do it to know if you get another error on another line because this one is gone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You would be doing yourself the biggest favour, because that kind of asking questions will yield better answers faster. Nobody can debug a stacktrace without code - an incomplete stacktrace at that. You should not waste 300 reputation points for nothing. Thank you.

Comment: Concerning `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`: Why are you hiding the very exception causing the problem? That is so counter-productive! The exception you are showing is only the symptom, not the root cause of the problem.